# Citation behaviors are different in Microsoft Office Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Citation behaviors are different in two different cases when I use Microsoft Office Word 365 on Windows 10 (v. 2004). Is it a bug? See screenshots below for reference.

I want display `Nguyễn Ngọc Quang (2016)` not `Quang (2016)` . Constraint: Not use `Corporate author`, because I need sort by Firstname (`Quang`, `Diệp`). Behavior like `Trương Ngọc Diệp` is what I expected. But the behavior in 2 cases are different.

Why they are different, how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When cite

[image]

```
(Quang, 2016)
```

and

```
(Trương Ngọc Diệp, 2012)
```

This is what I see in the XML itself:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is my file (thesis): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ahIU4S7bCu27phra8_lQofwLDsktGnpJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you say, “But the behavior in 2 cases are different.” What are the two cases? Maybe I am confused, but is it the difference between Microsoft Office Word 365 and something else? Or just the difference between two different citation methods?

Comment: The different behavior in same software (Microsoft Office Word), in same PC (Windows 10 version 2004), in same version (Office Word 365), same file ( `2020_10_17_Hoan thien phan tich BCTC tai Cong ty CP Tin hoc vien thong Petrolimex.docx`), at same time (23:57 PM GMT +7). 2 cases are 2 different reference sources. I tested, changing type `Book` or `Report` did not resolve the problem.

Comment: I see a light: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/96348827-c68add80-10d5-11eb-89c5-bcd34da0f0f8.png https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/96348834-cdb1eb80-10d5-11eb-8b60-d97a71213d6f.png but it is very irrelational.

Comment: One citation is a Report and the other is a Book.  This comes done to the style of the citation and absolutely isn’t a bug.  If you change Book citation to a report the behavior would be the same.  You would have to modify the citation style itself.  That isn’t easy.  **This is the reason I build my citation list manually.**